# Dispose multiple contexts from list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dispose

I have collection (**testRunEntities**) that stores multiple database contexts and I would like to dispose them in one go in "using" block way.

My only idea is enveloping this code in try{} catch{} finally{} and iterating all over collection. 
However I would not like to catch any exceptions in this method as it should be done by caller.

Is there any other way of doing it? Cleaner way?

```
using (TestManagementEntities testManagementEntity = new TestManagementEntities(TestManagementConnectionString))
{
    IEnumerable<TestRunsEntities> testRunEntities = null;

    try
    {
        testRunEntities =
            SomeNamespace.GetReportContextsForPeriod(null, null, testManagementEntity);

        List<string> softwareVersionsResult = await Task.Run(() => DatabaseWrapper.GetSoftwareVersions(
                    selectedProject,
                    testManagementEntity,
                    testRunEntities));
        CB_SoftwareVersion.DataSource = softwareVersionsResult;
    }
    //catch
    //{
    //  throw;
    //}
    finally
    {
        if (testRunEntities != null)
        {
            foreach (TestRunsEntities testRunEntity in testRunEntities)
            {
                testRunEntity.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `catch{}`, try/finally is how using works.

Comment: What would happen if an exception was thrown? Would it be caught in the caller?

Comment: If there is no `catch` then it would just be thrown as normal, pretty much the same as if you had `catch{ throw; }`. The difference being that the `finally` would run regardless.

Comment: Nice to know. I will update my question and mark it as solved then since I think that it is the cleanest possible way to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I do not need to "throw" an exception to handle it by the caller but I can just remove the catch{} block.

Also try{} finally{ object.Dispose(); } works like using statement in this scenario so I have achieved my goal.

Comment: `Also try{} finally{} works like using statement so I have achieved my goal.` not sure what you mean there, but definitely a `try/finally` is far from working like a `using` statement. If you mean it works as a `try {} finally { object.Dispose(); }` then yes :-)

Comment: Yup I meant this exactly ;) will add it to answer.